# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve..." in TS Gatsby Node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, webpack

I have a (node) server folder located in the root of my project, it is a Gatsby app written in Typescript

Here is one of the errors:

```
#27 27.94 ERROR in ./server/modules/version/index.ts
#27 27.94 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../common/api/cache' in '/build/server/modules/version'
#27 27.94  @ ./server/modules/version/index.ts 7:16-49
#27 27.94  @ ./server/index.ts
```

The module it is referring to is this:

```
export class StatusCache {
  private _cache: Record<string, CacheObject> = {};
  private options: CacheOptions = {
    expiresMinutes: 3
  };
...
```

and the import in the other file is `import { StatusCache } from "../../common/api/cache";`

the folder structure of the area of interest:

```
server
- common
  - api
    - cache (StatusCache class location)
- modules
  - <version>
    - index.ts
```

and lastly my webpack.server.js

```
const path = require("path");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const OUTPUT_FOLDER = "dist";

module.exports = env => ({
  entry: "./server/index.ts",
  mode: "production",
  target: "node",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              logInfoToStdOut: true,
              logLevel: "info",
              allowTsInNodeModules: false,
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.(test|spec)\./)
  ],
  externals: {
    bufferutil: "bufferutil",
    "utf-8-validate": "utf-8-validate",
    "mongodb-client-encryption": "mongodb-client-encryption"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "server.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, OUTPUT_FOLDER),
    publicPath: "/"
  }
});
```

Comment: Those are cache files. Have you tried running a `gatsby clean` and `gatsby develop`?

Comment: My project runs fine locally -- it fails on building the server within a Docker container which is built with this command: `webpack --config webpack.server.js`. I don't believe it's necessarily a Gatsby issue

Comment: Thanks for tagging Docker -- I didn't think to add it, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me and might be useful for others.

I added and edited my tsconfig-server.json to this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./server",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}
```

particularly the baseUrl, target, and moduleResolution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Error , the problem was in gatsby-config,I had to add ignore property like so :

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `data`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/data/`,
    ignore: [`**/\.*`], // ignore files starting with a dot
  },
},
```